# Function returned by redux-thunk is called where?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Below is my action creator and redux thunk function. I want to know the function returned by addUser is called where ?

```
 const userAdded = () => ({
  type: types.ADD_USER,
});

export const addUser = (user) => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}`, user)
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log("resp", resp);
        dispatch(userAdded());
        dispatch(loadUsers());
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };
};`enter code here`

I want to know the function returned by addUser is called where ?
```

Answer (score 0):

**userAdded** is an action and It should be dispatched by  [dispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#default-dispatch-as-a-prop) method.

It should be like this

```
dispatch(userAdded())
```